# count the amount of distinct cells only when a number is in the adjacent cell

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I need to count the amount of distinct cells only when a number is in the adjacent cell

```
VC 1    5
VC 1    4
VC 1    4
VC 1    3
VC 1    3
VC 2    




VC 2    
VC 2    
VC 2    

VC 2    
VC 2    
VC 3    1
VC 4    


VC 4    
VC 4    

VC 5    3
VC 5    4
```

For example 
in Row A

```
{=SUM(IF(A1:A25<>"",1/COUNTIF(A1:A25, A1:A25), 0))}
```

This would give me **5** different values for test in row A which is correct, but I only want distinct values to be tallied if the distinct value has a number next to it.

The Conditions which are met would be VC1, VC3 and VC5 so the answer would be **3**

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A1:A25<>"")*(B1:B25<>""))/(COUNTIFS(A1:A25,A1:A25,A1:A25,"<>",B1:B25,"<>")+(A1:A25="")+(B1:B25="")))
```

[image]